# Transform a table - convert the column with semicolons separated values into multiple columns with Yes / No entries

Tags: r, excel, normalization

I would like to convert my current table into one that can be easily filtered.

I have a table where the first column is a unique identifier, the second column is a list of issues separated by semicolons that are relevant for that entry. In addition to this I have some columns that are well defined and laid out. My table may look something like this:

```
|ID|Issue|Title|
|ABC.001.0001|Green; Blue|Around and up|
|ABC.001.0002|Green; Orange|Over and beyond|
|ABC.001.0003|Pink; Orange|Inside out|
```

Each | above represents the end of a column in the table.

I would like to transformed table to be easy to work with and issue to be easy to filter on. This would be a good result:

```
|ID|Green|Blue|Orange|Pink|Title|
|ABC.001.0001|Yes|Yes|No|No|Around and up|
|ABC.001.0002|Yes|No|Yes|No|Over and beyond|
|ABC.001.0003|No|No|Yes|Yes|Inside out|
```

I would prefer not to write a lot of code. I would like to find some libraries that can do this conversion in a few steps such as in R or Octave. Otherwise perhaps there are some steps I can take in MS Excel and MS Access to achieve the same result.

Just a as a side question what is this conversion called? Tidy data? Normalization? Munging?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `cSplit` from `splitstackshape` to split the "Issue" column by semi-colon (`sep=';'`).  Specify the direction to `long` and then reshape it back to `wide` using `dcast.data.table`.  Then change the "values" in "Blue" to "Pink" columns to "Yes/No" based on whether it has NA or not.  But, it is always better to have the result as a logical index `TRUE/FALSE` compared to `Yes/No` (which we will get from the `!is.na` step).

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(data.table)
res <- dcast.data.table(cSplit(df, 'Issue', sep=';', 'long'),
                   ID+Title~Issue, value.var='Issue')

nm1 <- names(res)[3:6]
 res[,(nm1):=lapply(.SD, function(x) 
          c("No", "Yes")[(!is.na(x))+1L]), .SDcols=nm1]

 res
 #             ID           Title Blue Green Orange Pink
 #1: ABC.001.0001   Around and up  Yes   Yes     No   No
 #2: ABC.001.0002 Over and beyond   No   Yes    Yes   No
 #3: ABC.001.0003      Inside out   No    No    Yes  Yes
```

Or you could use `cSplit_e` (from @Ananda Mahto's comments)

```
 cSplit_e(df, "Issue", sep = "; ", type = "character",
                 fill = 0, drop = TRUE)
```

Or an option using `base R`.  Here, I used `strsplit` to split the "Issue" column and then `rbind` the list output to create "m1".  Create a vector of unique values ("lvls").  Check which of the "lvls" are in each rows of "m1" (`lvls %in% x`) using `apply` with MARGIN as "1".  Convert the logical vector to numeric by adding "1" to it ('x)+1L`) and use it as index for "Yes/No" values.

```
 df1 <-  df[-2]
 m1 <- do.call(rbind,strsplit(df$Issue, '; '))
 lvls <- unique(c(m1))
 df1[lvls] <-  t(apply(m1, 1, function(x) c('No', 'Yes')[(lvls
                                %in% x)+1L]))
 df1
 #            ID           Title Green Pink Blue Orange
 #1 ABC.001.0001   Around and up   Yes   No  Yes     No
 #2 ABC.001.0002 Over and beyond   Yes   No   No    Yes
 #3 ABC.001.0003      Inside out    No  Yes   No    Yes
```

#### data

```
 df <- structure(list(ID = c("ABC.001.0001", "ABC.001.0002", 
 "ABC.001.0003"), Issue = c("Green; Blue", "Green; Orange", "Pink; Orange"), 
Title = c("Around and up", "Over and beyond", "Inside out")), 
.Names = c("ID", "Issue", "Title"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: I'll give you my vote here, but I think you should not be encouraging the OP to use "Yes/No" values when a logical `TRUE`/`FALSE` option exists. I would have personally suggested `cSplit_e(df, "Issue", sep = "; ", type = "character", fill = 0, drop = TRUE)`.

Comment: Many thanks akrun and Ananda. This is just what I was looking for.